# It appears that the ability to include a UI wireframe on this site is broken

Tags: bug, support, status-completed, mockups

I started to ask a question on UX.stackexchange.com and I clicked to add a UI Wireframe and it doesn't seem to allow me to save.

After setting up my wireframe which worked fine, I clicked "Save and Close" and all i see if an empty white popup that never seems to go away (see screenshot below).  I have included a screenshot below.

I get the same behavior using Chrome v37 or Firefox v32 on Mac.

[image]

Comment: Yup, I'm getting this too. Chrome on Yosemite, Chrome on Win8.1

Comment: Yes, same here actually. Not sure what's going on here, I'll see if I can get the SE comms team to have a look.

Comment: Definitely an issue I introduced with Stack Snippets. I'm working on a fix as we speak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should now be resolved and the fix is live across all sites. Sorry for the inconvenience; I broke it when modifying how the Markdown editor worked for Stack Snippets.

Comment: thanks for the quick turnaround . much appreciated